# Graph Modelling a 'transitive' relationship

Tags: neo4j

This is a followup to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61299233/3526600) that I had posted and accepted an answer. I have a further question after getting feedback, and trying to post as a new question to hopefully get an answer.

Having discussed with users, the requirement just got more complex. What they actually do is something like a table in relational world with following columns (its denormalised with lot of repetitive data:

`PartnerName | Service  | Offered?        |CurrentlyUsing  | WeCouldSellThese  |`

`XX          | Baking   | Yes             |Competitor A, B | Product A         |
 XX          | Baking   | Yes             |Competitor A, B | Product C         |
 XX          | Baking   | Yes             |Competitor A, B | Product D         |
 XX          | OnlyDough| Yes             |Product A       | Product C         |
 XX          | Packing  | No              |                | Product E         |`

Basically, they need to store information what is being used currently, and whether its currently offered by partner or not, they still try to sell them products (Offered Yes or No will both still lead to a market). There is a many-to-many relationship between service and product as well...which means there is a "3node" relationship - A particular partner for a particular product for a particular service, here are the 2 options I'm thinking of. The trouble with Option 1 is that Product A would have many To_Build outgoing relationships, so I dont have a way to figure out its for which partner.

[image]

Here are the options after I bring a new entity to split the relationship:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an extra node (say, labelled "Build") to "reify" the "3-node relationship". For example:

[image]

*By the way, you should also consider whether the `Could_Offer` relationship is redundant. For example, you could add an `isOffered` property to the `Could_Build` relationship and  eliminate the `Could_Offer` relationship.*

Comment: I need the Could_Offer relationship to store the state of whether that partner offers that service or not. It's a boolean property on the relationship.Let me think about your suggestion, thank you.

Comment: You could just add an `isOffered` property to the `Could_Build` relationship and  eliminate the `Could_Offer` relationship.

Comment: thanks! your reify idea is great!
Have a look at the two options I have for a new entity  - i've added to the original question as edit.

Comment: Your 2 options are structurally identical to each other; it is up to you how you name things. I would still recommend eliminating the redundant `Could_Offer` relationship by just moving the `Offers` property to the new outgoing relationship from the `Partner` node.